# How do you escape commas in uploaded CSV's for Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Have what I thought was a simple problem, I'm not able to upload a CSV into Dialogflow's Knowledge due to the following error:

> CSV documents must have exactly two columns. The provided document has 3 columns.

I realised quickly that for whatever reason Dialogflow didn't like the way I was escaping commas in each column. Consider the following example:

```
This is column 1\,line 1,This is column 2 line 1
```

Validates via CSV Lint so it should work, but doesn't. I've also tried escaping commas with double quotes, but still get the error.

Any ideas appreciated?!

Comment: have you tried `"This is column 1,line 1","This is column 2 line 1"` ?

Comment: Wow that was it! I had tried _"This is column 1, line 1",This is column 2 line 1_ but never thought about escaping the second column if it didn't include a comma. Thanks very much!!

Comment: glad that helped, i am writing it as answer please accept+upvote

Answer (score 3):

To escape the comma's in a row of csv we have to put the string inside double quotes.
So correct way will be :

```
"This is column 1,line 1","This is column 2 line 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @sid8491 for answering. The solution for Dialogflow is to escape every row in your CSV around quotes, even if you only have one column that uses a comma. So the example above is correct:

```
"This is column 1,line 1","This is column 2 line 1"
```